# File Permissions for XAMPP (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I tried this:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
sudo usermod -a -G daemon john
sudo find . -exec chown john:daemon {} +
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +cd   <-problem child
```

It goes fine until the last command which gives me "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

So Wordpress cannot add or delete plugins etc...
thoughts?

Comment: I'm certain a webserver should *not* have any write privileges to htdocs, ever. If you need your PHP software (wordpress) to write to certain locations, a) these should be outside htdocs, imho, and b) these should be very selectively made writable, not blanket.

Comment: You have an obvious error into what you have posted. If you run `find ... -exec ... +` and there are more characters after `+` then you get the error you describe.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the reply. Not sure what .htdocs has to do with this. In any case, we are on localhost, so the security level is not so important (I wouldn't think).

Comment: the folder you're operating in is called "htdocs", and it's typically the folder that your webserver serves publicly.

Comment: ok @thanasisp ran that line without "cd" restarted lampp and seems to be good to go. thx